# php email confirm code algo?

Tags: php, algorithm, confirmation-email

I saw a 'confirm_code' column in a db table, and property of the column is `varchar(100)`,
can you guys give me idea of a nice algo for a confirmation code ? Basically, it should consist of a random characters. The simplest things in my mind is just encrypting a string through `md5` or `sha1` but it won't fit because of the current column property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An md5 hash should easily fit in a varchar(100)... in hex form an MD5 hash is [typically 32 characters long](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#MD5_hashes).

Comment: ok, got it, it was my mistake i got a wrong syntax my sql query tnx anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can generate unique ID's with [uniqid()](http://php.net/uniqid).